# Search for a category

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to search for a specific category of email in all Outlook folders and move them to the "closed" folder if found.

Answer (score 0):

that will Need quite some code. First to run through alle Folders you Need something like this:

```
Sub run_alle_folders()
   Dim Ol, Mf, Mf1, mf2, Ns, mf3, mf4, mf5, mf6, i&
   On Error Resume Next
   Set Ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set Ns = Ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   For Each Mf In Ns.Folders
      for each item in Mf
          check_for_categorie_and_move(item) 'this should call your code
          next
        For Each Mf1 In Mf.Folders
            for each item in Mf1
                check_for_categorie_and_move(item) 'this should call your code
                next
          For Each mf2 In Mf1.Folders
               for each item in Mf2
                   check_for_categorie_and_move(item) 'this should call your code
                   next
            For Each mf3 In mf2.Folders
                 for each item in Mf3
                     check_for_categorie_and_move(item) 'this should call your code
                     next
               For Each mf4 In mf3.Folders
                   for each item in Mf4
                       check_for_categorie_and_move(item) 'this should call your code
                       next
  Next
   Set Ns = Nothing: Set Mf1 = Nothing: Set Mf = Nothing: Set Ol = Nothing: Set Tb = Nothing
   Set mf2 = Nothing: Set mf3 = Nothing: Set mf4 = Nothing: Set mf5 = Nothing: Set mf6 = Nothing
End Sub
```

For checking category andd moving the item (which I would put into a separat Sub) you should find enough code quite easily.

Max

Comment: Don't just loop through all items in a folder - this is extremely inefficient. Use FindFindNext or Restrict. You should also never use "for each" when you are moving the items - use a down loop (from Count down to 1)